# Open a new bash with sudo powers without reentering the password

Tags: bash, terminal, sudo, privileges

I find very useful to have more terminal tabs in different current working directories. But if I need sudo privileges I need to reenter the password for every shell.

Is there not a way to extend the sudo credential caching to a new shell or terminal, without doing it by default to all tabs?

PS: I do not want a root shell or terminal.

Comment: Caching cleartext passwords for further use certainly isn't one of `sudo`'s features, for obvious security reasons. `sudo`'s timeouts, on the other hand, are tty-dependant.

Comment: (The answer is not specific to the terminal or shell)

Comment: D'oh, didn't see the duplicate when I was writing my answer. I agree this should probably be closed as a dup.

Comment: @Leiaz: about duplication, I updated the question.

Answer (score 1):

The following in `/etc/sudoers` should give you per-user rather than per-user-per-tty credential caching:

```
Defaults   !tty_tickets
```

According to the `sudoers` man page,

> sudoers uses per-user time stamp files for credential caching.  Once a user has been authenticated, a record is written containing the uid that was used to authenticate, the terminal session ID, and a time stamp (using a monotonic clock if one is available).  The user may then use sudo without a password for a short period of time (5 minutes unless overridden by the timeout option).  By default, sudoers uses a separate record for each tty, which means that a user's login sessions are authenticated separately.  The tty_tickets option can be disabled to force the use of a single time stamp for all of a user's sessions.

Whether or not it is advisable to use this feature is up to you.

Comment: `By default, sudoers uses a separate record for each tty`: is there not a way to copy the record for the new tty instead?

Comment: I guess in theory you could use your root privileges you could rewrite the timestamp file used by sudo to track credential caching to include a record for a new tty of your choosing.  You'd probably need to take a look at the sourcecode of sudo to make sure you are writing the contents correctly.